# Comparing values of select boxes

Tags: javascript

I have 5 select boxes on a form. The first one has values from 0 to 8. The other four have values from 0 to 2.
I want to be able to compare the total value of the last four with the value of the first one with a javascript function.
So, for example, if I choose 6 in the first select box, the total of the last four select boxes should be 6 as well in any possible combination (e.g. 2 + 2 + 2 + 0, or 2 + 1 + 1 + 2, etc).
Can anyone help?
Many thanks!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

```
var box_1 = document.getElementById("box_1").value;
```

will give you the value (as a string) of the input in

```
<form>
    <input type="select" id="box_1"/>
</form>
```

as will `$("#box_1").val();` if you're using jquery

Then `var box_1_number = new Number(box_1);` to convert it from a string to an actual number, and you can compare it with other numbers.

eg. `if(box_1_number == box_2_number + box_3_number + ...)
{
    //do some stuff
}`

But there are many other ways, I'm sure.

Comment: Seriously, though, what _have_ you got so far?